# How to log non-interactive bash command sent through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I'm sending a command through ssh:

```
ssh server.org 'bash -s' << EOF
ls -al
whoami
uptime
EOF
```

How to log it in the system (remote server)? I'd like to log those commands in some file (.bash_history or /tmp/log).

I've tried to add the line below to sshd_config:

```
ForceCommand if [[ -z $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then bash; else echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" >> .bash_history; bash -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"; fi
```

But it logs "bash -s" only.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` in your second attempt?

Comment: After you put that `ForceCommand` directive into your config, did you try the exact same command that you tried the first time, or did you try a different command?

Comment: i've tried the same one

Answer (score 0):

When bash shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the ~/.bash_logout file. Probably you can run the history command at the end in the .bash_logout(of the server) and save it to some location.

Comment: Unfortunately .bash_logout is not run on non-interactive ssh.

Answer (score 0):

- If it suffices to work with the given command, we can put the necessary additions to enable and log command history at the beginning and end, e. g.

  ```
  ssh server.org bash <<EOF
   set -o history
  ls -al
  whoami
  uptime
   history|sed 's/ *[0-9]* *//' >>~/.bash_history
  EOF
  ```
- Or we could put them into the awfully long `ForceCommand` line:

  ```
  … if [[ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" == bash* ]]; then echo "set -o history"; cat; echo "history|sed 's/ *[0-9]* *//' >>~/.bash_history"; else cat; fi | bash -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"; fi
  ```