# How to log bash commands executed non-interactively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to log bash commands executed non-interactively.

Example:

on execution of `ssh user@a.b.c.d ls -l` command, it should be logged on `syslog`.

Found a   [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101253/how-to-log-non-interactive-bash-command-sent-through-ssh) but no help. Is there any way to achieve it by making code changes in bash package source code?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Have look you looked into [logger](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html)?

Comment: Are you looking to capture who executed a command, or its output, or something else? On the remote server or on the host where you run ssh to log in to the remote server?

Comment: i want to just log on the remote server syslog that which command is executed remotely

Comment: Is it not already being logged in `auth.log`? You can configure this in the `sshd` preferences.

Comment: No, it's not logged in auth.log.  My requirement is to put logs in syslog. sshd preferences will log only ssh related logs...."ssh user@a.b.c.d ls -l" it's just an example here .... i want any non-interactive command to be logged to syslog.

Comment: Is it practically possible to get log (in syslog) of non-interactive commands?